# Private network of ethereum blockchain of 4 nodes not syncing all time

Tags: synchronization, blockchain, ethereum

**Private ethereum network** of 4 nodes is not syncing well. I have created a private network of four nodes, For some time at strating all four node sync properly, if we make ant transactions, the transactions reflect on all 4 nodes i.e no of total blocks is same for all 4 nodes, but after some days/time all 4 nodes does not remain in synchronisation i.e. no of total blocks is not same for all nodes.

Why is this happening ? I am using geth **version 1.5.9**.

Comment: This is not programming related. Please read the [help about asking questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: @Richard How this is not programming related ?

Comment: @rohansethi: configuring an application across a network is not programming.